# How to make code greyed-out in comments

Tags: text, editor, editing

I know this might already be answered in the markdown help, but my English is not very good.

How do I make code greyed out, so you can distinguish between text and code in comments?

For example:

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, 
COUNT(*) 'Anzahl Aufträge'
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.id, customers.first_name, customers.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

to make your code greyed-out you need to click `{}` symbol and paste your code

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, COUNT(*) 'Anzahl Aufträge' FROM customers JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id GROUP BY customers.id, customers.first_name, customers.last_name"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And for comments it would be ´code´ and you paste your code in there?

Comment: Yes indeed `Code` requires ` `